# How add data directly to the arrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to use this code from [Bluetooth - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#QueryingPairedDevices)

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
// If there are paired devices
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
    // Loop through paired devices
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
        mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
}
```

But I cant add data to **`myArrayAdapter`, because it placed in `private void onCreate()`** and add method throws error that there is no such adapter.

I need to add data directly to the arrayAdapter because it should refresh listview in my activity when some new devices found.

Also I could use `myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, but like I have said my `ArrayAdapter` placed in `onCreate` so it cant access it.

So my question is how to place arrayAdapter outside of `onCreate` without any errors?

My java class with code if neccesary:

```
public class DeviceList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

        BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (BTAdapter != null) {
            if (!BTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBT, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            if (BTAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                BTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }
            BTAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter;
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inputELM);
        myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myEntries);
        listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

        // Register the BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter);
    }

    ArrayList<String> myEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                String devs = device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress();
                myEntries.add(devs);

            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand about fields / member variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place is outside `onCreate`

```
public class DeviceList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    // Declare here 
    private ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

        BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (BTAdapter != null) {
            if (!BTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBT, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            if (BTAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                BTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }
            BTAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inputELM);
        myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myEntries);
        listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

        // Register the BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter);
    }

    ArrayList<String> myEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                String devs = device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress();
                myEntries.add(devs);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write

> ArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter;

with your static variable declaration, so you can access it from all the methods. Then you can access it from anywhere.